# Как в твиттере реализована функция реагирования на нажатие?

Tags: твиттер, javascript, вёрстка, html5

1. Захожу в твиттер
2. Вожу логин/пароль
3. Вижу какой нибудь твит
4. Навожу на него курсор
5. Вижу надпись ретвитнуть
6. Изучаю код
7. Ни вижу никаких span и onclick, хотя реагирование при касании происходит
8. Вижу только class и неизвестный мне data-modal

А теперь сам вопрос - **Как разработчики это сделали и как мне узнать, какой код выполняется при клике?**

Comment: Тенденция вашего мышления несомненно радует. Надёюсь вы не остановитесь на этом и вскоре доберётесь до кварков и хиггсовых полей.

Comment: Какое право @Sleeping Owl имеет *восстанавливать* удалённый мной ответ!? Удалил - значит так надо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль разработчика Вам в руки и усердство в голову)
Разбираться в упакованном коде твиттера не очень приятная идея. Но если всё же интересно, в одном из загружаемых .js есть такая функция:

```
this.$tweetForEvent = function(a, b)...
```

Ищите её, через неё обрабатываются некоторые события на странице, в том числе и клики по ретвитам. У них там целый движок написан, а Вы onclick...

Answer (score 2):

Значит надо в javascript искать. Типа `$('.class').click()`, ну у них там свой фреймворк скорее всего, но суть та же.

Comment: Автор, видимо, удивлён, что не видит подключенных с помощью JS после загрузки страницы листенеров прямо в DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, в Твиттере дополнительные опции твита (Ретвитнуть, В Избранное) появляются не при клике по твиту, а при наведении на него курсора. Во-вторых, обработчик события не обязательно устанавливать в HTML-теге, его можно установить и непосредственно из JavaScript. Вот пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("one").onmouseover = function() { document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block"; }
                document.getElementById("one").onmouseout = function() { document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none"; }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">one</div> <div id="two" style="display: none;">two</div>
    </body>
</html>
```